# Raspbian MPM error after php 7.4 to 8.0 upgrade

Tags: php, apache2

On my raspbian (buster) I can get rid of the following error after upgrading php from 7.4 to 8.0 :
`Configuration error: No MPM loaded`

When trying to enable mpm_prefork it says that it doesn't exist :
`ERROR: Module mpm_prefork does not exist!`

I did installed libapache2-mod-php :
`apt-get install libapache2-mod-php`

The `apachectl -M | grep 'mpm'` command return :
`mpm_event_module (shared)`

But when trying to enable php8.2 with `a2enmod php8.2` I'm getting :

```
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php8.2:
ERROR: Module mpm_prefork does not exist! 
ERROR: Could not enable dependency mpm_prefork for php8.2, aborting
```

I have no clue anymore, help would be appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The install command is `sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-prefork`.

However, make sure you know what you are doing, what is installed, etc.

Some configurations disable `mpm_prefork` and use `mpm_event` instead. To know requires reviewing your Apache configuration, which modules are enabled and configured, the application requirements, PHP versus PHP-FPM configuration, etc.

It is also possible that you have a mix of both PHP 7.4 and PHP 8.0 configured, which is breaking your Apache configuration.

In the worst case, you might need to uninstall PHP 7.4 and PHP 8.0 completely. Then install PHP 8.0.

Note: PHP 8.2 is the current version. Use 8.2 unless you have requirements for 8.0.

Comment: `apt-get install apache2-mpm-prefork` does not find any version to install

Comment: ok let me try to install 8.2 then.

Comment: ok same result with 8.2
```:~ # a2enmod php8.2
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php8.2:
ERROR: Module mpm_prefork does not exist!
ERROR: Could not enable dependency mpm_prefork for php8.2, aborting```

Comment: @akaii - I explained in my answer, before doing anything, make sure you know what you are doing. Otherwise, you are going to make your problems worse. You need to know how your Apache is configured and what dependencies they have. Does your system need mpm_prefork or mpm_event? You must review the Apache configuration files to know what you have set up. Edit your question with details on these items.

Comment: ok it seems to be mpm_event I edited the question with the result.

Comment: @akaii - Was your system set up for PHP or PHP-FPM? My guess is PHP-FPM. Try these commands assuming PHP 8.2: `sudo apt install php8.2-fpm` and `a2enconf php8.2-fpm`. Notice any warning or error messages. You will probably need to disable the PHP 7 modules and confs.

Comment: you guess it well thanks for the solution @john Hanley